# Misaligned baseline in Arabic with iOS system font

Tags: ios, fonts, alignment, arabic

I have a UILabel with Arabic text which contains the word اسماً, last character is the letter [Alef](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%8B) with the mark [Fathah](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fathah). This mark is somehow causing the word to be misaligned vertically with the rest of the text.

[image]

When removing the mark, the word is back to correct baseline

[image]

The font is iOS system font, this doesn't happen with the Ariel font.

Comment: All iOS bugs should be reported to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the iOS system font.

I've opened a new project to test it and added only a UITextField  with an Arabic string which includes the char  اً  as the placeholder and it had the same behaviour.

This has been fixed on iOS 11.

[image]